# Displaying custom filed content instead of post content

Tags: custom-field

Plugin allow to add a custom field in post/page.

In post/page, i create a custom field, so user can input content on this field.

And i want if user input to this field, the post/page will display this content on screen, instead the main content that input via post/page editor.

Anybody can let me know how to do this ?

It is a plugin, so i can not edit template.

I have tried with add_filter -> the_content , but it seems only apply for post type, how to make it works with both post/page type ?

```
add_meta_box(
            'st-page-builder',          // Unique ID
            esc_html__( 'Page Builder', 'page-builder' ),       // Title
            'pageBuilderCallBack',      // Callback function
            'post',                 // Admin page (or post type)
            'advanced',                 // Context
            'default'                   // Priority
        );

function pageBuilderCallBack($object, $box) {
    wp_nonce_field( basename( __FILE__ ), 'page-builder-nonce' );
    $page = get_post_meta($object->ID, 'page_builder', true);
    require_once 'form-input.php';
}

function displayCustomContent() {
    // how to replace main post content with custom content ?
    if (is_page() || is_single()) 
    {
          global $post;

          $pageBuilderContent = trim(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'page_builder', TRUE));

          if ($pageBuilderContent) {
               return $pageBuilderContent;
          }
     }

     return $content;
} 

add_filter('the_content', 'displayCustomContent');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to check for that custom field and return that instead of post content.

```
function displayCustomContent() {    
    if (!is_front_page()) return $content;
    // how to replace main post content with custom content ?
    global $post;
    $special_content = get_post_meta($post->ID,'page_builder',true);
    if (!empty($special_content)) { 
        // remove_all_filters('the_content');
        return $special_content;
    }
    return $content;
}
```

The only other thing you might want to do is run your filter first...

```
add_filter('the_content', 'displayCustomContent', 1);
```

... and then uncomment [`remove_all_filters('the_content');`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_filters) inside the callback function. That should reduce unnecessary overhead and also help to avoid having other content filters alter your content.

Comment: thank you, that is what i want :) and if i want to do it with page type, only need check global $post, $page;

Comment: i want it apply for all post/page type. Simple replace with special content if it exists on this post/page.

Comment: I do not understand the question in the previous comment but you can add or remove as many conditions as you need to make it work the way you want.

Comment: i have updated this code, you can see and let me know the different the if (is_page() || is_single()) and if (!is_front_page()) return $content;

Comment: In an earlier version of your question you mentioned that you wanted to "display this content in front page" so I use `!is_front_page`-- "not is front page"-- to return the default content for all pages except the front page. `is_page() || is_single()` does something similar but different. That will be `true` for either a page or a single post display. The Codex entries for those functions will give you the details.